# Angular Route dont call subscription when called itself

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-router

Following is my code, the subscription debugger hits first time when Page LOAD and component load first time , when button is clicked and `search` function is called. the subscription from nginit dont hit.

Any idea why

```
public search(): void {
    debugger;
    this.router.navigate(['/logs/error'], { queryParams: { file: this.searchQuery }});
}

ngOnInit() {
    this.sub = this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
        debugger; // (+) converts string 'id' to a number

        // In a real app: dispatch action to load the details here.
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to track when the *query* parameters change, you need to use

```
this.route.queryParams.subscribe(...)
```

Not *params*