# Cannot refresh information with navigate angular2

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-routing, router

I have a little bit of a problem with the angular navigator 2
I'm in my detail projects page and I have a component that is in my detail page that will show me the next project.

So in my component I recall the same page which is' /projects/id

when I click in the navigation bar it changes the id well but the content does not change and I do not understand why because I make a router. navigate of my page.

my init controller projectDetail

```
ngOnInit() {
this.nextProjectId = this.activedRoute.snapshot.queryParams.nextProject;
const id = this.activedRoute.snapshot.params.id
this.projectsService.projectsAll().then( (projects) => {
  if (projects[this.nextProjectId]) {
    this.nextProject = projects[this.nextProjectId];
  } else {
    this.nextProject = projects[0];
  }

});
this.projectsService.projectFind(id).then( project => this.project = project);
```

}

my function navigate in component nextProject

```
nextProjectDetail(id, nextProject) {
const next = parseInt(nextProject, 0) + 1
this.router.navigate(['projects/', id], { queryParams: {nextProject: next }}).then(
  function(){
      console.log('navigate success');
  },
  function(){
      console.log('navigate failure');
  }
);
```

}

I even tried to use this function in the init of detail projects to see when the url changes but it doesn't work.

```
this.params.subscribe(params => {
   console.log("dfsd");
 });
```

there is another way to refresh the same page in a component on the same page?

thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46934833/angular-route-dont-call-subscription-when-called-itself/46935149#46935149

Comment: Thank you for your answer, your solution works but it is based on queryParams. but I did find a method based on the road.  `this.routeParamsMap.subscribe(params =>{ console.log("Good");})`

Comment: Well seems you are using queryparams? At least based on your code :) So shouldn't your code look like in the answer?